# Running Data / Race Data

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm interested in measuring my performance (as a runner) against a large pool of statistics to grade myself overtime and understand how I am improving.

I'm familiar with the [WMA tables](http://www.runscore.com/Alan/AgeGrade.html) and how to calculate an age graded score, but I'd like to use more granular datasets (with actual finish times, ages, genders, different distances...etc) in order to visualize how I compare and what my next goal should be.

Does this kind of dataset exist? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: see this related answer https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12736/1511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware that such a dataset exist.
But almost every race organiser (including the ones at amateur levels) put the results (often organised by age, gender, ...) online, publicly accessible.
Unfortunately they are usually not directly downloadable which means you have to scrap them from the web site or parse a PDF document.
An example is the Boston marathon data from 2001 to 2014 which have been collected in [a GitHub repository as CSV files](https://github.com/llimllib/bostonmarathon) by Bill Mill.