# Non-aggregated age of endurance sport competitors

Tags: data-request, sports, demographics

I'm looking for the actual age of competitors in endurance sports events (marathon, triathlon, ironman, etc). This can be any event, but it should be the age at competition time (36) and not the age bracket (34-39).

Any format, any license.

---

The **aggregated** data may look like this, but I look for **non-aggregated**, or at least a distribution per age:

[image]

([source](https://medium.com/running-with-data/the-new-york-city-marathon-2017-9acc6607b433))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is open data on with the ages of Boston marathon contenders, on Kaggle, in CSV format, and for years 2015-2017

https://www.kaggle.com/rojour/boston-results/data

or this dataset from 2001-2014

https://github.com/llimllib/bostonmarathon

Also, see this [related question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10210/1511)